# Soundcloud Embed - "Error calling method on NPObject!"

Tags: javascript, api, flash, soundcloud

I´ve been using the Soundcloud Widget for quite a while now. But since a week or so (I don´t know excatly) the error "Error calling method on NPObject!" occurs when trying to call a function like this one:

```
soundcloud.getPlayer('scPlayer').api_play( )
```

I followed the description from here: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget#methods

Is anyone else having these issues?
I´ve created a page where you can see the error live: http://threeam.de/vergelabs/soundcloud.html

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I switched to the HTML5 player (https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#methods). 
Works like a charm

Comment: It would also **[work like a charm](https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?enable_api=true&object_id=yourPlayerId&referer=&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fsober-rob%2Fhappy-jungle-animals-w-manitee-and-tama)** in Flash if you had put a **player.swf?url=https** instead of the currently used **player.swf?url=http** in your test page's source code. As for your website, I think HTML5 is better anyway to have all-device playback (inc mobile) for your site visitors. Flash is for advanced apps (like effecting the sounds in realtime etc or even making the music itself before upload).